# How can I access sqlite3 from PHP-File on Mac?

Tags: php, database, sqlite

I am a teacher and I try to access a sqlite3 database from my .php file with my students. This works great for windows user, but does not work for Mac user.

This is for example my delete function from the php.file. It works on windows but not on MacOS:

```
function deleteID(){
    $sql="DELETE from autos WHERE id=".$this->id;
    $con = new SQLite3($this->DBName);

    $auto = array();
    $auto['data']=array();
    $auto['error']=array();
    if($con->query($sql)){
        $auto['error'][0]['meldung'] = "Auto mit id=" . $this->id . " wurde gelöscht";
    }
    echo json_encode($auto);
}
```

This is the error message from the MacUsers:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  SQLite3::query(): Unable to execute statement: attempt to write a readonly database in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/AutoDBherstellenundgetDatarealisieren/data/auto.php</b> on line <b>62</b><br />
```

Do you have any idea how I can solve this? How can I change the permissions in a sqlite3 database?

Thank you very much. Best, Rainer

Comment: Are you running this script through a web server or from CLI? If the former, does the web server user have permissions to write to the file?

Comment: `$this->DBName` should point to a writable file/directory. Best practice is to create it in project root outside of public directory. You can also use [`is_writable`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.is-writable) to check if u can write to it.

Comment: @miken32 I run it from xampp. How do I access the permissions? THX

Comment: Get info from the Finder, or use `chmod`/`chgrp` command. If they are following common practice, the server will be running as user  and group "daemon" which needs to be given write access. Easiest step would be to give the "daemon" group write access.